# size issue when using a png as a fallback to svg

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg, png

Ok, I have run into a bit of a problem with svg...

I am currently using modernizr script as a fallback for older IE versions which swaps the svg to a png extension.

The only problem is that I am using widths to control the svg sizes:

```
<img src="img/testing.svg" width="200px">
```

(but in the long run I won't be putting the width there I will be putting it in CSS for media queries for it to scale up and down)

At the moment I am using this modernizr script:

```
if(!Modernizr.svg) {
  $('img[src*="svg"]').attr('src', function() {
      return $(this).attr('src').replace('.svg', '.png');
  });
}
```

That was working great as I tested it in Ie and it was swapping it out no problem, but one thing I did notice is that if for example my png is "200px wide" and in my css I have stated the svg version to be "400px wide" - it is scaling my png up which is resulting in blurring.

I guess my question is how do I stop the png from scaling up beyond its original size to prevent pixelation?

Or alternatively is there a better way of dealing with svg's and png fallbacks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not posted your CSS. But could it be you are using `img { max-width: 100%; }` ?

To prevent PNGs from scaling, you could try this:

```
img[src$=".png"] {
  max-width: none;
}
```